# SharePoint Online ULS Log

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I want to get the ULS error log from SharePoint Online site. I'm using the following SPO powershell but it doesn't get any result. I also tried to use the correlation ID parameter but it returns nothing...

> Get-SPOTenantLogEntry

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161388.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161369.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not working, Even though the command available in SPO powershell. If you asked the  Microsoft Office 365 Engineering team, they will confirmed it this is something which is not possible right now.

Best way to open a support case with Office 365 community and provide them the correlation id.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Contact-Office-365-for-business-support-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b

Answer (score 5):

Despite the Cmdlet and CSOM classes/methods the ULS log of SharePoint online is only available for Microsoft Support Engineers.